freeipa + freeradius = kerberos ticket issue
I would like your help to fix next issue What we need. We configured freeradius server to use it as authentication method for freeipa users. When we use option password (I mean password configured in ipa server itself) everything works. If we change authentication method to RADIUS we have next problems. User password on ipa client not cached. So if users go home with laptop and have no access to ipa server they can't log in to their ubuntu.
Behavior on ipa server:
User with local password
# kinit local-user
Password for local-user@OUR.DOMAIN.COM:

It works
krb5kdc.log
Dec 11 17:57:23 our.domain.com krb5kdc[1571](info): AS_REQ (4 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192(20), aes128-cts-hmac-sha256-128(19), aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96(17)}) 10.0.0.1: NEEDED_PREAUTH: local-user@OUR.DOMAIN.COM for krbtgt/OUR.DOMAIN.COM@OUR.DOMAIN.COM, Additional pre-authentication required
Dec 11 17:57:23 our.domain.com krb5kdc[1571](info): closing down fd 11

Rows below after enter password
Dec 11 17:58:17 our.domain.com  krb5kdc[1571](info): AS_REQ (4 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192(20), aes128-cts-hmac-sha256-128(19), aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96(17)}) 10.0.0.1: ISSUE: authtime 1733932697, etypes {rep=aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192(20), tkt=aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192(20), ses=aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192(20)}, local-user@OUR.DOMAIN.COM for krbtgt/OUR.DOMAIN.COM@OUR.DOMAIN.COM
Dec 11 17:58:17 our.domain.com krb5kdc[1571](info): closing down fd 11

RADIUS user
#kinit radius-user
kinit: Pre-authentication failed: Invalid argument while getting initial credentials

So ticket not created
krb5kdc.log
Dec 11 18:04:26 our.domain.com krb5kdc[1571](info): AS_REQ (4 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192(20), aes128-cts-hmac-sha256-128(19), aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96(17)}) 10.0.0.1: NEEDED_PREAUTH: radius-user@OUR.DOMAIN.COM for krbtgt/OUR.DOMAIN.COM@OUR.DOMAIN.COM, Additional pre-authentication required
Dec 11 18:04:26 our.domain.com krb5kdc[1571](info): closing down fd 11

Additional strange behaviour. If i try to log in to ipa server via ssh with local user it asks me password. If I try to log in to ipa server with radius user it asks me first factor and second factor. it accepts password for the first factor and empty 2nd factor. And let's me log-in.
Thank you in advance. I can provide any additional info
I already tried play with kerberos settings and nothing helps me

There is nothing strange here. You should really read documentation.
'otp' and 'radius' preauthentication methods in MIT Kerberos require use of FAST channel to encrypt communication between the client and the KDC.
The following section in RHEL IdM documentation explains it all in detail:
https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/accessing_identity_management_services/logging-in-to-the-ipa-web-ui-using-one-time-passwords_accessing-idm-services#retrieving-an-idm-ticket-granting-ticket-as-an-otp-or-radius-user_logging-in-to-ipa-in-the-web-ui-using-a-password
